# Firebase querying data having childs as uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Users is my root node, in that I have various childs created by getting the `uid` of the user who authenticated. Within these childs (`uid`) their are various childs like Info, General maintenance, Complaints.

I want to show some of the details like `gCity`, `gProductModel` from General maintenance child from all the users (`uid`s). Each uid will have a different values of `gCity`, etc. Under General Maintenance, I want to retrieve all that data by setting it on an adapter and `listview`.

I am not able to retrieve it.

Database image

[image: Database image]

retreive code

[image: retreive code]

When i am trying to retrieve data from the current user by using 'getuid()'(As shown below) ,its working fine . But when i try to retrieve all users data using' getkey()' , it isn't working .

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
.child(user.getUid())
.child("General Maintenance");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(list_users.size() > 0)
                list_users.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                Generalperson user = 
                 postSnapshot.getValue(Generalperson.class);
                list_users.add(user);
            }
                if(list_users.size() != 0)
                { ListViewAdapter adapter = new 
            ListViewAdapter(ServicehistoryActivity.this, list_users);
                list_data.setAdapter(adapter);}
            else
                {
                    list_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    k.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of your code and the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual code and JSON as text. You can easily get the latter by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userId = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference userIdRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
            ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("General Maintenence").getChildren()) {
                        String gCity = ds.child("gCity").getValue(String.class);
                        String gEmail = ds.child("gEmail").getValue(String.class);
                        String gPhone = ds.child("gPhone").getValue(String.class);
                        //and so on
                    }           
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            userIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

If you get this error, `Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied` is because you are not authorized to the Database, check the Rules Tab in the Realtime database and make this change:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: using getUid() will show the details of the current person who is using it right? My problem is that i want to retrieve gCity, gEmail from general maintenance child of all the users .

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Having the `uid` from the authentication you can use it in your `DatabaseReference`.

Comment: But My problem is that i want to retrieve gCity, gEmail from general maintenance child of "all" the users and show them simultaneously by setting an adapter on a listview

Comment: Please see my updated answer for getting the data of all users.

Comment: The getKey() provides only last token in the location pointed to by the reference, so how will i get the entire users key.

Comment: It isn't retrieving any data and in android monitor warn statements ,its showing this - Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: This error isn't because the code is not working, is because `Firebase Rules`. Please see my updated answer. The code should work for sure.

Comment: ya, now i changed the rules..so now that warning is not being shown. Their is no error in the code but its not retrieving any data , even though i have data in general maintenance child of all the users. The getKey() returns key of which user - first,last or any random key existing in the database?

Comment: This line `String userId = dataSnapshot.getKey();` returns those random generated keys. You need them in order to iterate down in your tree. That error is not about the code i provided you is about the `ListView ` that you are using. Try to solve this problem regarding the `ListView `, try my code and please keep me posted.

Comment: The listview is working perfectly when i am trying to retrieve the same info using the current user uid (by using getuid()) ...like this -        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("General Maintenance");  The data is being shown in the listview wen i am doing like this , but something is not going rite when i am using the code you provided.

Comment: The updated code is able to retrieve data but only of one user -the last user of the tree. Only the data of the last user is being on shown on the listview, other users data is not being shown.

Comment: I understand. You need now to get this lines `ListViewAdapter adapter = new 
            ListViewAdapter(ServicehistoryActivity.this, list_users);
                list_data.setAdapter(adapter);}` out of the `for loop` and your problem you'll be solved.

Comment: I placed out of the for loop but its not working, then i tried to place at some other places like -after usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
then also it didnt work..can u tell me where exactly to place it

Comment: Thanks alot for helping me out...now its working perfectly!

Comment: You need to put thise lines after the `else statement` ends. In `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: Now i noticed one problem that i am getting those values only "General Maintenance" is present in the 1st user of the tree,....if "General Maintenance" child is not present in the 1st user but its present in the 2nd or 3rd user ...then i am not getting any values...Here its not that General Maintenance will be ther for every user...if a particular user clicks on it ...then only the child will be created....Please help...Urgent

Comment: This question is not related with the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: its related to the question...please help..its urgent